# I want to add a filter in my MySQL Query in main WHERE from Sub-Select result

Tags: mysql

i have a booking table from the SQL query like

```
SELECT p.ID AS order_id, p.post_date AS BookingDate,
(SELECT pm.meta_value FROM test_postmeta pm WHERE pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = 'token') AS Token,
(SELECT pm.meta_value FROM test_postmeta pm WHERE pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = 'BookingFrom') AS BookingFrom,
(SELECT pm.meta_value FROM test_postmeta pm WHERE pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name') AS Firstname,
(SELECT pm.meta_value FROM test_postmeta pm WHERE pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name') AS Lastname
FROM test_posts p

WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order' AND p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
```

Now i want to add WHERE Token = '2021-123' to have only the order with this token.
I tryed with

```
WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order' AND p.post_status = 'wc-processing' AND Token = '2021-123'
```

I get the error with Unknown Field 'Token'.
The test_postmeta have more lines with the same post_id. This is why pm.meta_key = 'token' in WHERE. So i cant join this table with p.id = pm.post_id.
Later i want to add more filter like

```
WHERE BookingFrom = '2021-10-01'
```

What is the best solution?

Comment: Token is a alias column so you can not use it in where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rephrase your query using conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    p.ID AS order_id,
    p.post_date AS BookingDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'token' THEN pm.meta_value END) AS Token,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'BookingFrom' THEN pm.meta_value END) AS BookingFrom,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' THEN pm.meta_value END) AS Firstname,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' THEN pm.meta_value END) AS Lastname
FROM test_posts p
LEFT JOIN test_postmeta pm
    ON pm.post_id = p.ID
WHERE
    p.post_type = 'shop_order' AND
    p.post_status = 'wc-processing'
GROUP BY
    p.ID
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'token' THEN pm.meta_value END) = '2021-123';
```

Note that with this change in place, we can assert the token value in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much. The right solution i need.